# Cron job backup remote folder to local folder with wget over ftp

Tags: cron, backup, wget

Hi everyone would do with some advise

Can not get this simple task working

```
0 17 * * * wget -m ftp://usarname:password@host.com:port/remote/folder -P /local/folder
```

what im doing wrong ?

if i run it in terminal line:

```
wget -m ftp://usarname:password@host.com:port/remote/folder -P /local/folder
```

it is working as expected but if i add under crontab -e nothing happens.
I would like cron job to check files every day at 17:00 for changes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to restart cron service. Now just need to make it all end to end encrypted. 
if you make any changes to services do not forget to restart them :)

```
restart cron
```